# can i change the color of the squiggles in roslyn

Tags: c#, roslyn, vsix

Is it possible to change the squiggle color when writing a diagnostic analyzer?

I hate the green and red, and would like to make it like blue, or something. I also want it not be squiggle and instead be like a straight line.

Is this something we can change? I didn't find any APIs for it.

Answer (score 1):

When writing a diagnostic analyzer, you can't choose the color, you can only choose the DiagnosticSeverity, which then decides how is it displayed to the user, based on Visual Studio settings.

So, for example, you can set the color of Infos to blue in your VS. But it would affect all Infos, not just those from your analyzer and it won't affect  other users of your analyzer.

Comment: do you have ideas on how I could tell some other component that is a more traditional VS component to put things on the IDE? I basically have my analyzer written, but I want to make these changes .. so if I can somehow tell VS about location of things, (like the nodes to highlight, that would be great).

Comment: @user986697: I think an `IClassifier` can do it, but you might need an `ITagger` with an adornment provider.